# Regex Регулярное выражение для DateTime

Tags: регулярные-выражения, asp.net-mvc

есть тип datetime в котором пользователь указывает дату своего рождения, хочу написать regex, которое выдаст ошибку если пользователю меньше 18 лет. как мне это сделать?
допустим пользователь ввёл дату: 06.05.2009 надо что бы появилось сообщение что минимальный возраст 18+

Comment: зачем `regex`? у вас ведь есть дата, вот на основе этой даты и сравнивайте, что пользователю < 18

Comment: Приведите примеры валидных и невалидных строк в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: regexp для данной цели - это примерно как алебардой резать колбасу, не удобно, избыточно, но может сработать... В любом случае нужно уточнить вопрос, потому что сам regexp - это шаблон соответствия поиска и он не вернет сообщение...

Comment: @PotroNik вообще формально, заменой по регулярке можно сделать сообщение :)

Comment: @teran заменой будет заниматься `.replace` же и подобное, а шаблоном для поиска соответствия к замене будет рег

Comment: Каждый день новую регулярку писать?

Answer (score 1):

вам не регулярные выражения тут нужны, а проверку даты при вводе. что-то наподобие такого.

```js
$("#d").change(function(){
   let [ y, m, d ] =  $(this).val().split('-'); 
   let n = new Date();
   let c = new Date(n.getFullYear(), m-1, d);      
   
   let age = n.getFullYear() - y - (c > n);   
   
   $("#age-error").toggle(age < 18);      
});
```

```css
#age-error {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="d">

<span id="age-error">вам меньше 18</span>
```